# How to read a series of path locations and append

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a series of paths for 200 files in the form of tsv. I want to have the code open each of the file paths and append them all together. The columns are the same.

I have tried turning the series into a data frame or a list and tried reading it but there is an error of either invalid syntax or method issue.

This is just a series of the complete paths of about 200 line items:

```
x = America 
df = []
for path in America: 
    df_1 = pd.read_table(America)
    df.append(df_1)

final_df = pd.concat(df, axis =0)
```

I am not able to execute the code at all and even after doing some research was not able to find a similar code to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `America` is a sequence of file paths...

```
import csv
final = []
for path in America:
    with open(path) as f:
        final.extend(list(csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')))
```

Without using the csv module:

```
final=[]
for path in ['foo.csv','foo1.csv','foo3.csv']:
    with open(path) as f:
        final.append(f.read())

final = ''.join(final)
```

Writing all the data to a new file:

```
with open(newfilepath, 'w') as newfile:
    for path in ['foo.csv','foo1.csv','foo3.csv']:
        with open(path) as f:
            newfile.write(f.read())
```

---

The last two solutions rely on each file ending with a newline character.